# docker command not running

Tags: docker, nginx

I am new to docker and trying to run the following codes and getting the error below.

```
Nihits-MacBook-Pro:~ nihit$ docker container run --publish 80:80 nginx

Unable to find image 'nginx:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/nginx
bc95e04b23c0: Pull complete 
110767c6efff: Pull complete 
f081e0c4df75: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:004ac1d5e791e705f12a17c80d7bb1e8f7f01aa7dca7deee6e65a03465392072
Status: Downloaded newer image for nginx:latest
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint gracious_pare (0a28a065694108085e2b7533870d9d84889899baf5d4130c58c49c4736bb6b12): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:80: unexpected error (Failure EADDRINUSE).
ERRO[0016] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

I tried different codes with port but all of them get stuck and don't do anything.

```
Nihits-MacBook-Pro:~ nihit$ docker container run --publish 3000:80 nginx
Nihits-MacBook-Pro:~ nihit$ docker container run --publish 8080:80 nginx
```

None of them work and just are stuck on the terminal.

Comment: I got this error when a service was already running in my host machine bound to the port I was going to publish :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
docker container run --publish 3000:80 nginx:latest
```

Since I read the above conversation, it looks like you recieved a long string of number meaning that docker is running, just hit the url `localhost:3000` you will see nginx running.

Normally `port:80` is used by php if you have apache installed on your computer.

If it gets stuck it also means that the docker is running but not in the background.
Normally the `--detach` or `-d` means that the docker will provide you the long string of numbers which tells docker to run the app in the background so you won't see anything happening in the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Would you mind to try the below command to start the nginx again?

```
$ docker run -d -p 80:80 nginx:latest
```

BTW, all commands which start with "docker container" seems the new commands from docker.

But, according to the https://docs.docker.com/edge/engine/reference/commandline/docker/,

the function of "docker container run" should be same as "docker run".

Not sure why difference between those two commands.

In my cases, I'm seldom to use the commands which start with "docker container" to execute my container.

If the container successfully started, the shell will return the message such as follows:

```
sh-3.2# docker run -d -p 8080:80 nginx:latest
b0a5aa7965119c5b2705392b5b9e9640a4ab8edefda6722ee86da507229cdf05
sh-3.2#
sh-3.2# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE         COMMAND            CREATED
b0a5aa796511   nginx:latest  "nginx -g 'dae...  About a minute ago...
```

Comment: Actually now it gives me a string c5ad07c99829b35989422ff6f48dbdea716c54908528d5ed08287d327e72693a

Comment: would you mind to let me know the result of executing the " docker ps -a" on your machine?

Comment: docker container run --publish 3000:3000 nginx:latest --- I treid the command and it looks like it worked, but when I go to broweser and type localhost:3000 it doesnt work ....even the code you wrote works in that sense but when I go to the browser and type localhost:8080 it doesnt show anything.